# How to super position an image in the corner of another one with object-fit

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an image renderer with a fixed height and width that displays images with all kinds of aspect ratios and I want to preserve these aspect ratios.

So far it's worked with this code

```
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
```

Now I want to position an icon in the bottom right corner of my image. I can't do a fixed position since `object-fit` make it so that not all images will have the same width.

Comment: Can you share some of your html? Are you only using <img> tag?

Answer (score -1):

This should set up how you desire. Note that I had to use a containing div and make it display: flex.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.main {
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="main" src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" />
  <img class="icon" src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" />
</div>
```

Comment: This works if it's a square or landscape image. What if you have many images with variable widths or a vertical photo?